# create python list with pair of numbers from text file -> solved

Tags: python-2.7

Using pyhton 2.7.
Output should be:

```
CARS_List = ((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

In the text file are totally 6 cars.
The source where to get the numbers from are in a text file with:

```
car1="description of car1"
car2="description of car2"
[..] up to
car6="description of car6"
```

I have already read the car numbers from the text file (4th char in each line) and stored in a sorted list:

```
CARS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Using the list CARS, how to create the above mentioned CARS_List, thus starting and ending with parentheses and not brackets?

With thanks to user "bserra" it has been solved !

Solution:

```
CARS = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
CAR_list = [(CARS[0],i) for i in CARS if i != CARS[0]]
CARS_list.append(tuple(CARS))
CARS_list = tuple(CARS_list)
print CARS_list
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need that but the lines below should do the trick:

```
CARS = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
# Gives [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6)]
CARS_list = [(CARS[0],i) for i in CARS]
# Gives [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)]
CARS_list.append(tuple(CARS))
# Gives ((1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
CARS_list = tuple(CARS_list)

print CARS_list
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Only thing is that the last element in CARS_List has spaces:
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) in stead of (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: So you would have to be more specific in your question.
What do you want in CARS_list: a pure string with everything? or a tuple of tuples? or a tuple of strings?

Comment: see above starting with "Later:"

Comment: I fixed it by changing the 2nd command to: CAR_list = [(CARS[0],i) for i in CARS if i != CARS[0]]. Again: thank you bserra and problem solved !

Comment: Good to know, if my answer was good don't forget to accept it as an answer. Otherwise, add a response on your own with your complete fix. It will help others.